Image Pyramid. Having trouble creating the desired composite image
What I am trying to do:
Combine these two images:


Using this mask:

to create this output:

The assignment:

Write a program to create a composite image of the two images with the mask, based on image pyramids.

Now, This is what I have tried so far:
    import cv2
    import numpy as np

# Read the input images and the mask
    image1 = cv2.imread("figure2-assignment3.jpg")
    image2 = cv2.imread("figure3-assignment3.jpg")
    mask = cv2.imread("figure4-assignment3.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# Smooth out the mask
    mask = cv2.GaussianBlur(mask, (5, 5), 0)

# Convert mask to float32 and normalize to range [0, 1]
    mask = mask.astype(np.float32) / 255.0

# Duplicate the mask to match the number of channels in the images
    mask = cv2.cvtColor(mask, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

# Generate Gaussian pyramids for both images and the mask
    gaussian_pyramid_image1 = [image1]
    gaussian_pyramid_image2 = [image2]
    gaussian_pyramid_mask = [mask]

    for _ in range(6):  
        image1 = cv2.pyrDown(image1)
        gaussian_pyramid_image1.append(image1)
    
    image2 = cv2.pyrDown(image2)
    gaussian_pyramid_image2.append(image2)
    
    mask = cv2.pyrDown(mask)
    gaussian_pyramid_mask.append(mask)

# Generate Laplacian pyramids for both images
    laplacian_pyramid_image1 = [gaussian_pyramid_image1[-1]]
    laplacian_pyramid_image2 = [gaussian_pyramid_image2[-1]]

    for i in range(5, 0, -1):  # Start from the second last level
       image1_up = cv2.pyrUp(gaussian_pyramid_image1[i])
       image2_up = cv2.pyrUp(gaussian_pyramid_image2[i])

    image1_resized = cv2.resize(gaussian_pyramid_image1[i - 1], (image1_up.shape[1], image1_up.shape[0]))
    image2_resized = cv2.resize(gaussian_pyramid_image2[i - 1], (image2_up.shape[1], image2_up.shape[0]))
    
    laplacian_image1 = cv2.subtract(image1_resized, image1_up)
    laplacian_image2 = cv2.subtract(image2_resized, image2_up)
    
    laplacian_pyramid_image1.append(laplacian_image1)
    laplacian_pyramid_image2.append(laplacian_image2)

# Generate Gaussian pyramid for the mask
    gaussian_pyramid_mask = [gaussian_pyramid_mask[-1]]
# Start from the second last level
    for i in range(5, 0, -1):  
        mask_up = cv2.pyrUp(gaussian_pyramid_mask[-1])
        mask_resized = cv2.resize(gaussian_pyramid_mask[-1], (mask_up.shape[1], mask_up.shape[0]))
        gaussian_pyramid_mask.append(mask_resized)

# Combine the corresponding levels of Laplacian pyramids using the mask
    composite_pyramid = []
    for img1, img2, msk in zip(laplacian_pyramid_image1, laplacian_pyramid_image2, gaussian_pyramid_mask):
        img1_resized = cv2.resize(img1, (msk.shape[1], msk.shape[0]))
        img2_resized = cv2.resize(img2, (msk.shape[1], msk.shape[0]))
        composite_level = img1_resized * msk + img2_resized * (1.0 - msk)
        composite_pyramid.append(composite_level)

# Collapse the composite pyramid to obtain the composite image
    composite_image = composite_pyramid[-1]
    for i in range(len(composite_pyramid) - 2, -1, -1):
       composite_image_up = cv2.pyrUp(composite_image)
       composite_image_resized = cv2.resize(composite_pyramid[i], (composite_image_up.shape[1], 
       composite_image_up.shape[0]))
       composite_image = cv2.add(composite_image_resized, composite_image_up)

# Save the composite image
     cv2.imwrite("composite_image_2.jpg", composite_image)

And this is the best I could produce:

Now what am I possibly doing wrong? I can get the hand, but the right side of the composite image is not the correct one.

there's an example in the opencv repo. your professor gave you this assignment wanting to see who'll find it.

Did you mean the Orapple one?

that's the one.

Yeah I just checked the orapple code, that does not help me. This task is quite advanced than that one.
Do you have any more suggestions for me that I can try?

excuse me, how is that different from what you were assigned? it is literally laplacian pyramids for blending.

APPROACH 1: Custom Alpha Blending (shorter)
I would not worry that much about using either Gaussian or Laplacian pyramids for this. Instead, you can perform alpha blending with a smoothed-out version of the mask provided (this ensures smooth borders) to arrive to the desired output. Here is my approach to solving your problem:
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Read the input images and the mask
mask = cv2.imread("mask.jpeg", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
image1 = cv2.imread("image-1.jpeg")
image2 = cv2.imread("image-2.jpeg")

# Resize images to match mask dimensions
height, width = mask.shape[:2]
image1 = cv2.resize(image1, (width, height))
image2 = cv2.resize(image2, (width, height))

# Smooth out the mask and normalize to range [0, 1]
transparency_gradient = cv2.blur(mask, (25, 25))
transparency_gradient = cv2.cvtColor(transparency_gradient, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
transparency_gradient = transparency_gradient / 255.0  # Normalize to range [0, 1]

# Perform manual alpha blending with transparency gradient
composite_image = image1 * transparency_gradient + image2 * (1 - transparency_gradient)

# Save the result
cv2.imwrite("composite_image.png", composite_image)

Which yields this final image:




APPROACH 2: Blending through Gaussian and Laplacian Pyramids
If the objective is to achieve such blending through pyramids, below is a code that does the trick:
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Read the input images and the mask
mask = cv2.imread("mask.jpeg", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
image1 = cv2.imread("image-1.jpeg")
image2 = cv2.imread("image-2.jpeg")

# Set the level of the pyramids (tweak it for better accuracy)
levels=6

# Resize images to match mask dimensions
height, width = image1.shape[:2]
mask = cv2.resize(mask, (width, height), interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)

# Duplicate the mask to match the number of channels in the images
mask = cv2.cvtColor(mask, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

# Generate Gaussian pyramids for both images and the mask
gaussian_pyramid1 = [image1.astype(np.float32)]
gaussian_pyramid2 = [image2.astype(np.float32)]
mask_pyramid = [mask.astype(np.float32) / 255.0]

for _ in range(levels - 1):
    image1 = cv2.pyrDown(image1)
    image2 = cv2.pyrDown(image2)
    mask = cv2.pyrDown(mask)

    gaussian_pyramid1.append(image1.astype(np.float32))
    gaussian_pyramid2.append(image2.astype(np.float32))
    mask_pyramid.append(mask.astype(np.float32) / 255.0)

# Generate Laplacian pyramids for both images
laplacian_pyramid1 = [gaussian_pyramid1[levels - 1]]
laplacian_pyramid2 = [gaussian_pyramid2[levels - 1]]
for i in range(levels - 2, -1, -1):
    expanded1 = cv2.pyrUp(gaussian_pyramid1[i + 1], dstsize=(gaussian_pyramid1[i].shape[1], gaussian_pyramid1[i].shape[0]))
    expanded2 = cv2.pyrUp(gaussian_pyramid2[i + 1], dstsize=(gaussian_pyramid2[i].shape[1], gaussian_pyramid2[i].shape[0]))
    laplacian1 = cv2.subtract(gaussian_pyramid1[i], expanded1)
    laplacian2 = cv2.subtract(gaussian_pyramid2[i], expanded2)
    laplacian_pyramid1.append(laplacian1)
    laplacian_pyramid2.append(laplacian2)

# Combine the corresponding levels of Laplacian pyramids using the mask
composite_pyramid = []
for laplacian1, laplacian2, mask in zip(laplacian_pyramid1, laplacian_pyramid2, mask_pyramid):
    mask_resized = cv2.resize(mask, (laplacian1.shape[1], laplacian1.shape[0]), interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
    composite_level = laplacian1 * mask_resized + laplacian2 * (1.0 - mask_resized)
    composite_pyramid.append(composite_level)

# Reconstruct the final blended image
composite_image = composite_pyramid[0]
for i in range(1, levels):
    composite_image = cv2.pyrUp(composite_image, dstsize=(composite_pyramid[i].shape[1], composite_pyramid[i].shape[0]))
    composite_image += composite_pyramid[i]

# Ensure pixel values are within valid range
composite_image = np.clip(composite_image, 0, 255).astype(np.uint8)

# Save Image
cv2.imwrite("composite_image.png", composite_image)

Which produces:

It's your choice now... Good luck! And may the code be with you...

Bro I have tried that and that created results with flying colors.
But I need to use Image Pyramids. That is literally the assignment.

@Catalanforyouforever I have re-run my code several times, and it produces the exact same image I included in my answer. Maybe, there's something wrong with your local set-up of Python, or your numpy/opencv libraries are outdated...

"with flying colors" is not to be taken literally

Oh, hahahah! My bad. I didn't know that idiom even existed, and since it made sense in the context of the question, the sentence didn't sound that off to me, so I took it at "face" value (pun intended). Good one...

Would you kindly remove your solution? This is misguiding others into thinking this is the correct answer just because it gets the job done. I need it to be done correctly.

I cannot remove my original answer, since it partially solves the problem and may be of interest to other StackOverflow users. Nonetheless, I have found a solution to your original problem. Hope this helps!
